# Xpath: Select property depending on other property's value

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I have this [partial] XML:

```
   <Events>
     <Properties>
       <Property Descriptor=100>1378314024</Property>
       <Property Descriptor=200>ABC1234</Property>
     </Properties>
     <Properties>
       <Property Descriptor=100>1378314022</Property>
       <Property Descriptor=200>123456</Property>
     </Properties>
     <Properties>
       <Property Descriptor=100>1378314023</Property>
       <Property Descriptor=200>123456</Property>
     </Properties>
    </Events>
```

How can I select `@Property Descriptor="100"` for the FIRST occurrence of 123456 on  `@Property Descriptor="200"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way :

```
(//Properties[Property[@Descriptor='200'][.='123456']]/Property[@Descriptor='100'])[1]
```